# MyBatis Spring Integration - some ResultSet values not set on POJO

Tags: mysql, spring, mybatis

I'm evaluating MyBatis and have encountered an issue which has been puzzling me for 5 hours. My next option is to debug the MyBatis source but I'm hoping somebody out there has encountered this issue.

**Here's my spring-config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder location="jdbc.properties"/>

<!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

<bean id='dataSource' class='org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource'>
    <property name='driverClassName' value='${jdbc.driverClassName}'/>
    <property name='url' value='${jdbc.url}'/>
    <property name='username' value='${jdbc.username}'/>
    <property name='password' value='${jdbc.password}'/>
</bean>

<!-- Declare a transaction manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<bean id="productMapper" class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean">
    <property name="mapperInterface" value="com.mybatis.test.mapper.ProductMapper"/>
    <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<!-- define the SqlSessionFactory, notice that configLocation is not needed when you use MapperFactoryBean -->
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <!--<property name="configLocation" value="mybatis-config.xml"/>-->
</bean>

<bean id="productService" class="com.mybatis.test.ProductService">
    <property name="mapper" ref="productMapper"/>
</bean>
```

**Here's my mybatis-config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="com/mybatis/test/mapper/ProductMapper.xml"/>
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

**Here's my mapping XML file (ProductMapper.xml):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper
        PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"
        "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="com.mybatis.test.mapper.ProductMapper">
</mapper>
```

**Here's my mapper Interface (ProductMapper.java):**

```
package com.mybatis.test.mapper;

import com.mybatis.test.pojo.Product;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.*;
import java.util.List;

public interface ProductMapper {

    String SELECT_ALL_PRODUCTS = "select product_id, address_id, manufacturer_name, model_reference, product_name, description, price, url, date_added, " +
        "create_user, update_user from product";

    @Select(SELECT_ALL_PRODUCTS)
    List<Product> getAllProducts();
}
```

**Here's my POJO (Product class):**

```
package com.mybatis.test.pojo;

import java.util.Date;

public class Product {
    private Integer productId;
    private Integer addressId;
    private String manufacturerName;
    private String modelReference;
    private String productName;
    private String description;
    private Double price;
    private String url;
    private Date dateAdded;
    private String createUser;
    private String updateUser;

    public Integer getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(Integer productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getManufacturerName() {
        return manufacturerName;
    }

    public void setManufacturerName(String manufacturerName) {
        this.manufacturerName = manufacturerName;
    }

    public String getModelReference() {
        return modelReference;
    }

    public void setModelReference(String modelReference) {
        this.modelReference = modelReference;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Date getDateAdded() {
        return dateAdded;
    }

    public void setDateAdded(Date dateAdded) {
        this.dateAdded = dateAdded;
    }

    public Integer getAddressId() {
        return addressId;
    }

    public void setAddressId(Integer addressId) {
        this.addressId = addressId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public Double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getCreateUser() {
        return createUser;
    }

    public void setCreateUser(String createUser) {
        this.createUser = createUser;
    }

    public String getUpdateUser() {
        return updateUser;
    }

    public void setUpdateUser(String updateUser) {
        this.updateUser = updateUser;
    }
}
```

**Here's my unit test:**

```
package com.mybatis.test.sql;

import com.mybatis.test.mapper.ProductMapper;
import com.mybatis.test.mapper.ProductMapperImpl;
import com.mybatis.test.pojo.Product;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import static junit.framework.Assert.assertNotNull;
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:spring-config.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ProductMapperTest {

    @Autowired
    private ProductMapper productMapper;

    private String systemUser;

    public void setProductMapper(ProductMapperImpl productMapper) {
        this.productMapper = productMapper;
    }

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        systemUser = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        Product product = getProduct();
        productMapper.insertProduct(product);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        productMapper.deleteProductByCreateUser(systemUser);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAllProducts() {
        List<Product> products = productMapper.getAllProducts();
        assertNotNull("Product list is null.", products);
        for (Product product : products) {
            assertTrue(product.getManufacturerName().equals("Western Digital"));
        }
   }

   private Product getProduct() {
       Product product = new Product();
       product.setManufacturerName("Western Digital");
       product.setProductName("My Passport Ultra");
       product.setModelReference("WDBZFP0010BBK-EESN");
       product.setDescription("USB3.0 1TB Hard disk drive");
       product.setPrice(new Double(48.99));
       product.setUrl("http://www.some web site.com");
       product.setDateAdded(new Date());
       product.setCreateUser(systemUser);
       product.setUpdateUser(systemUser);
       return product;
    }
}
```

**Here's the problem:**

Although the Product created in the test setup() method is successfully written to the mySql DB, the test fails because when the products are read from the DB, only the following fields have values set on the POJO (Product.class):

- description
- url
- price

All the other POJO fields are null despite having a value in the Product table in the database. I'm puzzled as to what is special about these fields. I'd appreciate any help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: In your *mybatis-config.xml*, declare as follows:

```
<configuration>
    <settings>
          <setting name="mapUnderscoreToCamelCase" value="true"/>
    </settings>
</configuration>
```

Option 2: Change SELECT_ALL_PRODUCTS to be:

```
String SELECT_ALL_PRODUCTS = "select product_id as productId, address_id as addressId, manufacturer_name as manufacturerName, model_reference as modelReference, product_name as productName, description, price, url, date_added as dateAdded, " +
  "create_user as createUser, update_user as updateUser from product";
```